# Pass function to another function in Scala, get "Missing parameter type for expanded function Scala"

Tags: scala, unit-testing, functional-programming, scalatest

I wrote the following test:

```
  "List" should "be [3, 4] for condition '_ <= 2'" in {
    val l: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
    assertResult(List(3, 4))(dropWhile(l, _ <= 2))
  }
```

For function:

```
  def dropWhile[A](l: List[A], f: A => Boolean): List[A] = l match {
    case Nil => List()
    case Cons(h, t) => if (f(h)) dropWhile(t, f) else t
  }
```

However, I get `missing parameter type for expanded function` when pass `_ <= 2` to `dropWhile(l, _ <= 2)`. What's the problem? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the way type inference works in **Scala 2**. At that point the compiler doesn't know yet that `A` is `Int` thus it doesn't know how to expand `_ <= 2`

There are multiple ways to solve this problem.

1. Use **Scala 3** which improved in this reward, and it should just work.
2. Manually specify the type parameter:

```scala
dropWhile[Int](l, _ <= 2)
// Or
dropWhile(l, (x: Int) => x <= 2)
```

3. *(my favourite one)* move the function to its own parameter list so that type inference works as expected in **Scala 2**; also it provides a better API IMHO.

```scala
// Definition site
def dropWhile[A](l: List[A])(f: A => Boolean): List[A] = ???
// Call site
dropWhile(l)(_ <= 2) // Or dropWhile(l)(x => x <= 2)
```